# Where can I find a shared asp.net hosting which support html5

Tags: web-hosting

I hope to test html 5 Offline Web Applications.

The server needs to be configured to respond with the correct mime-type, “text/cache-manifest”.

Where can I find a shared asp.net hosting which support html5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All hosts that support asp.net will be useful for you.
As for HTML5, it depends on the user's browser and not your hosting.

For offline cache, you need a host which support web.config, if it's the situation, add the follow code inside your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".manifest" mimeType="text/cache-manifest" />            
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: In my mind, asp.net hosting don't support htaccess

Comment: The server needs to be configured to respond with the correct mime-type, “text/cache-manifest”. In shared asp.net hostong , how can do that?

Comment: see my changed comment, and Godaddy windows hosting plan (http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting.aspx)

Comment: When I access index.html, it display "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: The offline cache are for mobile application?